# Azure Service Bus and MassTransit iConsumer business logic

Tags: azure, service, azureservicebus, masstransit

Hello new to Azure Service Bus and MassTransit but love the simplicity. I see most examples show a worker class to handle the Consume implementation in a consuming service. I assume then after the message is consumed and may have a JSON payload does the event model worker start the business logic with in the domain?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Also, there are many, many videos [on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLx8uyNNs1ri2MBx6BjPum5j9_MMdIfM9C) that show how MassTransit works.

Comment: Yes I'll check more of those out thanks Chris!

Answer (score 0):

A consumer, which is the most common consumer type, is a class that consumes one or more messages types. For each message type, the `IConsumer<T>` interface is implemented where `T` is the consumed message type. The interface has one method, Consume,

Below is the example of `IConsumer`  Interface

```
public interface IConsumer<in TMessage> :
    IConsumer
    where TMessage : class
{
    Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TMessage> context);
}
```

For complete Information check [Mass Transit Consumers.](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/consumers.html#consumer)